# fancybox closed but firing button disappeared

Tags: javascript, ajax, fancybox

I have following code to popup fancybox, when click "select_login button", the problem is after popup the fancybox, i cancel the fancybox by click the close X button on the top. the firing button("select_login") did not show up.

how can i make the "select_login" button show up again?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#select_login").fancybox({
                              autoOpen: false, 
                              width: 600, 
                              height: 400, 
                              padding: 0,
                         });

      $("#select_login").click(function() {

            var $username= $("#username").val();
            var $password = $("#password").val();
            var $pageTryLogin= $("#pageTryLogin").val();
            var retval;
            var $response;
            alert("clicked");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                  url: 'loginSelectAccount',
                  data:{clientId:$username, password:$password},
                  dataType: 'html', 
                success: function (data) {

                       $response=$(data);
                       retval = $response.find('#multiRecord').attr('value');


                      if (retval == 'false'){

                         $.fancybox.close(true);
                         $("#logFormid").submit();

                      } else if(retval == 'true'){

                         $response.find('#username').attr('value',$username);
                         $response.find('#password').attr('value',$password);
                         $response.find('#pageTryLogin').attr('value',$pageTryLogin);

                         $.fancybox.open({
                             content : $response.html(),
                              afterClose : function() {
                                  $.fancybox.close(true);
                             }
                         });

                      }
                }
            });
      });
});


<input type="button" name="selectLogin" id="select_login" value="Login" style="width:51px">                         
<input type="submit" name="loginTry" id="single_login" value="Login" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Comment: you may not need `$("#select_login").fancybox()` to launch fancybox since it's already bound inside the `.click()` method.

Comment: I think that your problem may be elsewhere. I put your code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPdwh/) and the "select_login" button does not disappear.  Looking at the code you posted, I don't see anything that would hide it either.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make any sense. You are attaching fancyBox to element by id "#select_login", but this element does not have "href" or "data-fancybox-href" attribute, so fancyBox displays this element instead as inline and hides after closing (like any inline element).